# Draw the outer envelope of multiple density graphs in one graph

Tags: r

I would like to draw the external outer envelope (contour) of a distribution graph which includes multiple density graphs and extract its value.

```
X <- c(1,2,1,4,3,1,2,8,9,0,5,4,2,2,5,5,7,8,8,9,5,6,5,6,3,4,5,3,4,5,4)
Y <- c(0,3,1,1,3,2,7,1,2,1,9,2,1,3,6,1,9,5,2,9,1,1,2,1,3,4,6,9,4,5,2)
Z <- c(1,4,9,5,7,8,2,8,9,0,5,4,2,2,5,5,7,8,8,9,5,6,5,6,9,9,9,2,6,7,1)
W <- c(1,8,9,7,8,9,12,3,11,21,5,4,8,8,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,3,1,9,2,1,8,4,1)
Q <- c(1,8,9,7,8,9,12,3,16,30,2,3,4,4,4,3,7,7,2,3,2,5,9,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,0)

n <- data.frame(X,Y,Z,W,Q)

plot((density(X)))
fun <- function(x)lines((density(n[[x]])))
t <- seq(1:length(n))
lapply(t,fun)
```

Have searched on web and I could find the contour but it can not be applied to a distribution graph generated as above.

Comment: I don't understand what graph you're trying to make. How would you combine a contour graph with a density graph?

Comment: Appologies Edited the name as it is called outer envelope not contour. There are a couple of good answers below to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are asking for what might be called the "outer envelope". My first effort had a couple of problems as you can see:

```
lines(  x= density(X)$x, 
        y=apply(  do.call( cbind, 
                  lapply(n, function(x){ density(x)$y})), 1, max), col="red", lwd=3)
```

And I think that also highlights problems with your efforts as well, since it illustrates the problems with not establishing a common grid on which to hang your density estimates.

[image]

So establish limits and re-do:

```
from=min(X,Y,Z,W,Q); to = max(X,Y,Z,W,Q)
png()
 plot( Xd <- density(X, from=from, to=to))
 fun <- function(x) lines(density(n[[x]],from=from, to = to  ) )
 t <- seq(1:length(n))
 lapply(t,fun)
 lines(  x= density(X, from=from, to=to )$x, 
         y=apply(  do.call( cbind, lapply(n, 
                     function(x){ density(x, from=from, to = to)$y})), 1, max), col="red", lwd=3)
    dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `y=apply(sapply(n,` be the same and a bit easier to read? Also I was trying to create a "simpler" version of this and saved the first `density` result and avoided calculating that again. No idea if that makes any difference in the end though.

Comment: I sometimes get (unpleasantly) surprised by the use of `sapply` when it stacks results rather than keeping them separate. I have found that leaving them separate is safer. Saving  X-density would make sense.

Comment: Thank you, would identifying and extracting the value points from the series used to graph the multiple distributions that form the outer envelope be possible.

Comment: You could use `which.max` instead of max to create a listing of which column the max values came from and then plot perhaps every tenth value up at 0.20 (after redrawing with a larger ylim in the plot call.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer very similar to BondedDust's (and based on his from/to approach) that I think is easier to read and possibly faster if the dataset is very large, because it doesn't calculate the densities twice.

```
from <- min(n)
to <- max(n)

t <- seq(1:length(n))
ds <- lapply(t, function(i) density(n[[i]], from=from, to=to)) #Densities
maxd <- apply(sapply(ds, "[[", "y"), 1, max) #Max y of each x

plot(density(X), type="n", ylim=c(0, max(maxd)), xlim=c(0, 15))
for (i in t) lines(ds[[i]])
lines(seq(from, to, length.out = length(maxd)), maxd, col="red", lwd=3)
```

I manually set the plot xlim for better visualization.

[image]